# Mapping xml to xml using PHP and Symfony 2

Tags: php, xml, symfony, mapping

I'm facing a problem to solve. I'm getting data in a structured XML format (quite complex with a lot of nested nodes) and I need to map it to a different domain.

So far I'm parsing input into entities using JMS Serializer.

And I've got output entities with JMS Serializer annotations to use the serializer for producing output XML.

The problem that I'm facing is mapping one set of entities to another. 
Any ideas on how to go about it? What strategies to look at?

Thank you : )
Chris